# gettin rJava to work for qdap? All 64bit I think?

Tags: r, rjava, qdap

I am trying to get qdap to work in rstudio, but I am having trouble getting rJava going. I am currently getting this error:

package ‘qdap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

> The downloaded binary packages are in     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWedT1h\downloaded_packages Error:
> package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’:  .onLoad failed in
> loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: inDL(x,
> as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)   error: unable to load
> shared object 'C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application. In
> addition: Warning messages: 1: package ‘qdap’ was built under R
> version 4.2.3  2: package ‘qdap’ was built under R version 4.2.3

It seems to suggest that there is an issue running 64 bit java with 32 bit r, which seems to be a problem a lot of people are having in the other stack exchange questions. But, I checked my global environment and my r version is also 64-bit:

> r version is: [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1

As far as I can tell, my Rstudio is too:

> RStudio
> 2023.03.1 Build 446 © 2009-2023 Posit Software, PBC "Cherry Blossom" Release (6e31ffc3, 2023-05-09) for windows Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.1+446 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3
> Safari/537.36

Any advice on what to try?